# Vanity URLs Dispatcher Cache Invalidation - Adobe AEM/CQ

Tags: adobe, aem

I was trying to configure the dispatcher invalidation configuration as per [Adobe Dispatcher Invalidation documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/page-invalidate.html). As per the documentation

> Cache invalidation requests for a page are also generated for any aliases or vanity URLs that are configured in the page properties.

I created a vanity URL in page properties dialog. When I publish the page for which Vanity URL property is set, I can see the logs in `disptacher.log`

```
checking [/dispatcher/invalidate.cache]
Activation detected: action=Activate [/content/geometrixx/en/products]
Touched /app/server/aem-apache/htdocs/cache/.stat
response.status = 200
response.headers[Server] = "Communique/2.6.3 (build 5221)"
response.headers[Content-Type] = "text/html"
cache flushed
"GET /dispatcher/invalidate.cache" 200 13 0ms
```

But when i check the configured (inside dispatcher.any) docroot cache folder inside Apache web server. Only cache corresponding to full page path is cleared (e.g. /content/geometrixx/en/products in logs). But the vanity URL accessed file (e.g. /mySite/prodct.htm) is still there.

Do we need to do more configuration for invalidating the cache for Vanity URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like there is a bug related to this functionality. I would suggest filing a support issue. Feel free to reference internal issue GRANITE-9224.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I am sorry, but am not able to get hold of link to check internal issue GRANITE-9224. Also is the link for filing a support ticket is https://daycare.day.com/home/createaticket.html. (Adobe ID is not working on this, do we need a separate account for this?).

Comment: Only certain users in each customer account are able to log into DayCare. If you don't know who these contacts are, your Adobe account manager should be able to help you out.